# Max value of collect_list(column) in Hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I am using below command in Hive. and getting correct result.

```
select acct_id,collect_list(expr_dt) from experiences
    > group by acct_id;
```

Output:

```
900      ["2015-03-31"]
707       ["2015-03-31","2014-12-10"]
903       ["2015-03-31"]
-435       ["2015-03-31"]
718       ["2015-03-31","2014-06-03"]
```

I want to get the max date for each account.

When I am trying execute below query I am getting error.

```
select acct_id,max(collect_list(expr_dt)) from experiences
    > group by acct_id;
```

and the error is -

> SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 1:19 Not yet supported place for
>   UDAF 'collect_list'

I want to do total operation in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with max without collect_list if your goal is to only find out max expr_dt for each acct_id group

**input:**

```
hive> select * from  experiences;
OK
900 2015-03-31
707 2015-03-31
707 2014-12-10
903 2015-03-31
-435 2015-03-31
718 2015-03-31
718 2014-06-03
```

**query:**

```
hive> select acct_id,max(expr_dt) from experiences group by acct_id;
```

**output:**

```
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 4 seconds 30 msec
OK
-435    2015-03-31
707 2015-03-31
718 2015-03-31
900 2015-03-31
903 2015-03-31
```